# 'more' is not recognized as an internal command error when aws command is run in cmd

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, path, aws-cli

I am trying to invoke a lambda function from commandline by using the below command.

```
aws lambda invoke --function my-date-time-app-myDateTimeFunction-Wo9bffa58kgY --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out --payload "{\"option\": \"date\", \"period\": \"today\"}" out.txt
```

**my-date-time-app-myDateTimeFunction-Wo9bffa58kgY** is my function name.
and ***{"option": "date", "period": "today"}*** are the parameters ,I am trying to write the response to **out.txt**

But am getting the below error

```
'more' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have installed aws command line tool and ***aws --version*** command works perfectly fine. If anybody came accross such issue can you please help

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the AWS CLI is attempting to call `more` as a pager, which is invoked when output is displayed on-screen.

You can **disable the use of a pager** by putting this configuration in the `~/.aws/config` file:

```
[default]
cli_pager=
```

See: [Using AWS CLI pagination options - AWS Command Line Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-pagination.html#cli-usage-pagination-clientside)